# css link behaviour overriding with another class

Tags: css

```
a:link {
  color:#034AFF;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.specialLink {
  color:#CCCCCC;
}
```

For the css above a:link overrides specialLink class. But I want specialLink class to override the default behaviour. BTW I cant remove a:link. So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
body a.specialLink {
  color:#CCCCCC;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the most elegant solution is this one:

```
a.specialLink:link /*, a.specialLink:visited*/ {
  color: #CCC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define again the a:link style. If doing this in another .css does not work, you may add the !important directive to override any other definition, but it may prove painful to mantain if you overuse it.